# Is it possible to edit the output of an Eclipse variable when making an External Tool?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am trying to make an External Tool in Eclipse which requires several file names as inputs.  However, I need to edit the output from the variable to exclude the file extension.

My arguments look as follows:

```
makeindex ${selected_resource_name}.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o ${selected_resource_name}.nls
```

The output from this compiles as follows:

`makeindex filename.tex.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.tex.nls`

However, I would like to remove the .tex extensions, so the command compiles as

`makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls`

Is this possible?  And if so, how can I do this from within Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i am seeing it looks like you are trying to replace '.tex' with '.nlo'. You could use substring to specify the name minus the last four characters (.tex). And do the rest as you were.

Example:

```
$new_name = substr(selected_resource_name, 0, -4);
makeindex ${new_name}.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o ${new_name}.nls
```

This should return your desired result.